# Windows 10 HDD to SSD for primary partition

Tags: windows-10, ssd, storage, disk-cloning, boot-partition

Just upgraded boot partition to a 480gb SSD and its so much quicker, but.. Now my primary partition  is divided as followed. [111.16GB System Reserved][224.53GB NTFS][111.333GB Recovery Partition] It pretty much split up all my storage into Recovery and Reserve leaving me with a very small portion of the disk. How can I shrink or remove this?

Comment: resize the **System Reserved** and **Recovery Partition** down to 600mb each.  See below for gparted.

Comment: USB is ready with Parted Magic but I cant seem to figure out how to boot the IOS on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Linux application like gparted which is a nice partition manager through a live cd of Linux or installation. Parted magic is a live CD partition manager which us quite good. Also you can use windows cd to shrink those partitions.
For example the best and convenient way is to use parted magic live cd.

1. Download the parted magic [iso](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/parted_magic.html).
2. Make a usb live cd ( Refer [rufus](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/parted_magic.html) ).
3. Restart your computer and boot into usb
4. You will be presented with a nice gui and you'll be able to resize the partitions with ease.

Comment: How do you use these programs.  The author clearly does not know how.  There are existing questions and answers to those questions, that explain in detail how to use those programs, but this answer does not explain how to use those programs.  *Comments should be kept to the comment section.*

Comment: @Ramhound please see if something more is to be edited

Comment: I purchased Parted Magic and downloading it to a Flashdrive

Comment: @Robbie I provided link to free version. Leave it aside do you know to boot into usb?